# Why services/hostnames defined in docker-compose can not be resolved

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a problem with accessing a container from another container. My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
  version: '2'
services:

  consul:
    image: "consul"
    hostname: "consul"
    command: "agent -server -client=0.0.0.0  -bind=10.30.1.134 -retry-join=10.30.1.97 -retry-join=10.30.1.42 -bootstrap-expect=3 -ui"
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"
      - "8500:8500"
      - "8300:8300"
      - "8301:8301"
      - "8302:8302"
      - "8600:53/udp"
    volumes:
      - /data/consul:/consul/data
    network_mode: host
  vault:
    depends_on:
      - consul
    image: "vault"
    hostname: "vault"
    links:
      - consul
    environment:
      VAULT_ADDR: http://127.0.0.1:8200
    ports:
      - "8200:8200"
      - "8201:8201"
    volumes:
      - ./tools/wait-for-it.sh:/wait-for-it.sh
      - ./config/vault:/config
      - ./config/vault/policies:/policies
    entrypoint: /wait-for-it.sh -t 200 -h consul -p 8500 -s -- vault server -config=/config/with-consul.hcl
```

When I do docker-compose up I see errors

```
vault_1   | nc: bad address 'consul'
```

And also I am not able to ping the service:

```
root@ip-10-30-1-134:~# docker run vault ping consul
ping: bad address 'consul'
```

According to the documentation the contaners must be acccessible by the name defined i.e. consul

Comment: Can you verify that Consul starts and runs successfully?

Comment: Yes consul starts and joins the cluster - I have consul cluster 2017/07/12 07:33:10 [INFO] agent: Join completed. Synced with 2 initial agents

Comment: I have just tested that if I add "172.18.0.1   consul" in vault container then all works fine. Now the question is why it is not working in docker-compose.yml

Comment: To test the dns, do this: `docker run --rm --net container:project_vault_1 nicolaka/netshoot drill consul @127.0.0.11` Be sure to replace `project_vault_1` with the actual container name of the first vault container that docker-compose brings up. This will create a container that shares the namespace with your vault container so you can test its networking environment. The 127.0.0.11 dns server is the internal dns server that docker runs. I noticed that you have a link specified for consul. You do not need to use link. What version of docker-compose are you using?

Comment: docker ps

`d95ff11519a4        vault               "/wait-for-it.sh -t 2"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8200-8201->8200-8201/tcp   cault_vault_1
9dceb1bc31c7        consul              "docker-entrypoint.sh"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                                      cault_consul_1
root@ip-10-30-1-134:~/cault# docker exec d95ff11519a4 dig @127.0.0.11 consul
rpc error: code = 2 desc = containerd: container not started`

Comment: DNS query says - container not started. Very interesting as from my humble opinion it is started

Comment: I have janly workaround - adding "extra_hosts" with consul : IP but there is no guarantee that the IP will be this each time I start docker-compose.